# Popup div makes flash message unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I have a the a div with an id of "popup" that pops up on my screen (with jQuery's show()) with the following css:

```
#popup
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;

    height: 130px;
    margin-top: -270px;

    width: 420px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

This div is used as a click event that starts recording a webcam video. The Flash webcam applet shows a message that requests access to the webcam. Unfortunately this message is unclickable since my div is above it.

See this image (where the pink block is the #popup div with a clickevent attached to start recording): [image: this image]

Is there any way to be able to "click through" the div or give the flash message a higher z-index, or maybe something else? I hope someone can help me out with advice!

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of the containing div to be lower than that of the container the flash sits in.

```
#popup
{
    position:relative;
    z-index: -50;

}
```

AFAIK, the flash pop-up is internal to the brower, and can't be styled.

You could possibly even try omitting the z-index in the #popup altogether.

*Edit* Did some googling, looks like setting the position of the element may help.

Comment: That removes the button because since it is under the flash as well.

Comment: In that case, add a new class to the button, and set it's z-index seperately.

Comment: 'You could possibly even try omitting the z-index in the #popup altogether' > Doing things with z-index do not seem to help. 'Position:relative;' is no solution either since I want to position the popup on top of the other div.

Comment: If you have access to the flash object, try adding  "wmode=opaque" to it

Comment: That will make the flash opaque if I read correctly. I want the flash message to be on top and after having clicked it I want the button to be on top. For now I see no way to accomplish this unfortunately. Maybe there is another solution. I will sleep on it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but it'll be an unreliable sollution, as there may be situations (smaller screen sizes for example) where the element will end up overlapping due to size constraints.

As for the wm-mode=opaque, after googling the issue, it seemed to be the popular sollution. Personally I'm not all that familiar with how flash objects work, but it wouldn't hurt to try it.

Comment: It seems to me though that the opaque element is used to get the flash *underneath* the HTML. I need it to get on top. :-)